dynamic вместо рефлексии
Интерфейс dynamic не особо сложный, пожалуй за определенное время можно аккуратно написать проброс рефлексии через интерфейс dynamic
Можно ли использовать nuget пакет, или какую то либу что бы не городить вот такое
public  DynReflect : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject {
  private object aObj; // Обьект назначения
  private Type   aType;// Тип обьекта назначения

  public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)  
    {
        var prop = aType.GetProperty(binder.Name);
        if (prop == null) {
            result = null; 
            return false;
            }
        result = prop.GetValue(aObj);
        return true;
    }

 }

Может уже есть готовое решение?
В данном случае есть COM-библиотека сторонняя, написана вообще непонятно на чем. Разработчик библиотеки неудосужился сделать портирование под с#.
Приходится писать нечто вроде
Type ComType= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ScriptControl") // Подключаем либу
var obj =ComType.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0]) // Вызов конструктора
Comtype.InvokeMember("Init", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[]{}); Вызов метода

Все COM-методы известны, но вызвать их получается только через рефлексию, вот и подумал через dymaic было бы удобнее написать нечто вроде
var a = DynReflect.CreateCOM("Класс");
a.Init();
a.BeginSession();
a.PrintComment("Hello");
a.EndSession();

Так гораздо читабельнее бы было.

версия .NET какая?

@aepot .NET framework 4.6.1, по-моему dynamic c 4-ой поддерживается без проблем.

Понял, молчу, очень старое, тогда нет советов. Единственное, что могу сказать - производительность всех этих наворотов ниже плинтуса. Убедитесь, что вы не наплодите тормозов.

а как это планируется использовать?

@Grundy для подключения COM библиотеки у которой нет портирования на C#. Приходится писать что то вроде Type ComType= Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ScriptControl") потом звать конструктор var obj =ComType.InvokeMember(null, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, null, null, new object[0])  потом вызывать методы рефлексией Comtype.InvokeMember("Init", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[]{}); Все методы известны, но вызвать их получается только через рефлексию, вот и подумал через dymaic было бы удобно.

А было бы удобнее var a = new DynReflect(obj);  a.Init(); a.BeginSession(). a.PrintComment("Hello") и т д.

@nick_n_a, добавь это все в вопрос. Готового решения нет, но dynamic действительно может упростить вызовы
